# What is the fastest way for calculating the sum of arbitrary large binary numbers

Tags: c, binary, addition

I can't seem to find any good literature about this. Having a `BigBinaryNumber` (two's complement with virtual sign bit) structure like this:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
enum Sign {NEGATIVE = (-1), ZERO = 0, POSITIVE = 1};
typedef enum Sign Sign;
struct BigBinaryNumber
{
    byte *number;
    Sign signum;
    unsigned int size;
};
typedef struct BigBinaryNumber BigBinaryNumber;
```

I could just go for the elementary school approach (i.e. summing individual bytes and using the carry for subsequent summing) or perhaps work with a fixed size look-up table.

Is there any good literature about the fastest method for binary summation?

Comment: Your code has some issues. `structure` should probably be `struct`; The line `enum Sign {NEGATIVE = (-1), ZERO = 0, POSITIVE = 1};` does not declare anything (type only).

Answer (score 2):

The fastest method for adding numbers is your processor's existing `add` instruction. So long as you've got the number laid out sensibly in memory (e.g, you don't have the bit order backwards or anything), it should be pretty straightforward to load 32 bits at a time from each number, add them together natively, and get the carry:

```
uint32_t *word_1 = &number1.number + offset, *word_2 = &number2.number + offset;
uint32_t *word_tgt = &dest.number + offset;
uint64_t sum = *word_1 + *word_2 + carry; // note the type!
*word_tgt = (uint32_t) sum; // truncate
carry = sum >> 32;
```

Note that you might have to add some special cases for dealing with the last byte in the number (or make sure that `*number` always has a multiple of 4 bytes allocated).

If you're using a 64-bit CPU, you may be able to extend this to work with `uint64_t`. There's no `uint128_t` for the overflow, though, so you might have to use some trickery to get the carry bit.

Comment: `*word_1 + *word_2` appears to be a problem.  If `sizeof(uint32_t) == sizeof(unsigned)`, then any "carry out" of `*word_1 + *word_2` is lost.  Maybe `((uint64_t)*word_1) + *word_2`?

Comment: Some processors implement and 'add with carry' operation ('adc' on x86 I believe). It allows you to add together any two arbitrarily large binary values. FAST.

Comment: @Jay Agree about the availability of 'add with carry' , etc., but `*word_1 + *word_2` does not compel the compiler to use [`adc` vs. `add`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Arithmetic).  At this part of this code, only 2 `uint32_t` operands are begin added with no need to preserve the carry.

Comment: This is just the elementary school approach? I already mentioned it. I agree on that for the sake of speed you should use the largest native integer size supported. I might test how much faster this is than using just `byte`.

Comment: @chux It's only a few lines of assembler to write a loop to add two blocks of binary of any length. Since you write it yourself you can use 'adc'. I should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" is to use the native (or maybe larger) integer size.

@duskwuff is on the money to walk through `number`, multiple bytes at a time.

As with all "What is the fastest way ...", candidate solutions should be profiled.

Follows is a *one* type solution so one could use the largest type as well, the native type or any 1 type.  e.g. `uintmax_t` or `unsigned`.  The carry is partiality handled via code and carry generation depends on testing if addition will overflow.

```
typedef unsigned MyInt;
#define MyInt_MAX  UINT_MAX

void Add(BigBinaryNumber *a, BigBinaryNumber *b, BigBinaryNumber *sum) {
  // Assume same size for a, b, sum.
  // Assume memory allocated for sum.
  // Assume a->size is a multiple of sizeof(MyInt);
  // Assume a->number endian is little and matches platform endian.
  // Assume a->alignment matches MyInt alignment.
  unsigned int size = a->size;
  MyInt* ap   = a->number;
  MyInt* bp   = b->number;
  MyInt* sump = sum->number;
  int carry = 0;
  while (size > 0) {
    size -= sizeof(MyInt);
    if (carry) {
      if (*ap <= (MyInt_MAX - 1 - *bp)) {
        carry = 0;
      }
      *sump++ = *ap++ + *bp++ + 1;
    }
    else {
      if (*ap > (MyInt_MAX - *bp)) {
        carry = 1;
      }
      *sump++ = *ap++ + *bp++;
    } 
  } // end while
  // Integer overflow/underflow handling not shown, 
  //   but depend on carry, and the sign of a, b
  // Two's complement sign considerations not shown.
}
```